# Undefined process.env Environment Variable in sveltekit

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, svelte, sveltekit

I'am using the new [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs) Framework with the `node-adapter`

and i have a problem of `undefined` Environment-Variables when using `process.env.APPLICATION_KEY_ID` Syntax in an endpoint in production build.

When i use:
`console.log(process.env)` i'am getting a list of all variables, including my `APPLICATION_KEY_ID`

```
ALLUSERSPROFILE: 'C:\\ProgramData',
APPDATA: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming',
APPLICATION_KEY_ID: 'test',
```

But when i use `console.log(process.env.APPLICATION_KEY_ID)`

i'am getting `undefined`

Can someone give me a hint what i'am doing wrong?

I'am running the app in kubernetes, this is my Dockerfile for building this image:

```html
# build the sapper app
FROM mhart/alpine-node:14 AS build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# install dependencies
FROM mhart/alpine-node:14 AS deps

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY --from=build /app/package-lock.json package-lock.json

RUN npm ci --prod

COPY --from=build /app/build build
COPY --from=build /app/node_modules node_modules

# copy node_modules/ and other build files over
FROM mhart/alpine-node:slim-14

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=deps /app .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "build"]

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

SvelteKit uses [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) as it's bundler.  It is probably best to stick to how this package deals with environment variables.  Which is to say, all env variabled prefixed with `VITE_` will be available in your code using `import.meta.env.VITE_xxx`

Comment: It seems not to work i'am also getting undefined with prefixed "VITE"

Comment: using VITE_ will expose your environment keys to the client side. Probably not something rubiktubik wants to do if they're building an API endpoint.

Comment: This applies to any of those environment keys if used in the client part of the application, the original question however mentions endpoints which are always only in the server.  But yes, you should always be careful of what you ship to your clients.

Comment: apparently not all `VITE_` prepended vars get exposed unless you call them from frontend code. https://vadosware.io/post/pattern-for-env-in-sveltekit/